# c# ms access database error ColumnCount property cannot be set on a data-bound DataGridView control

Tags: c#

Please help me to know whats wrong with my code, I'm stuck on this error, So please help me. thanks

```
       InitializeComponent();


        studentInfoDataGridView.ColumnCount = 6;
        studentInfoDataGridView.Columns[0].Name = "ID";
        studentInfoDataGridView.Columns[1].Name = "FirstName";
        studentInfoDataGridView.Columns[2].Name = "LastName";
        studentInfoDataGridView.Columns[3].Name = "Course";
        studentInfoDataGridView.Columns[4].Name = "StudentSection";
        studentInfoDataGridView.Columns[5].Name = "StudentNumber";



        studentInfoDataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

        studentInfoDataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        studentInfoDataGridView.MultiSelect = false;
```

Comment: Is there any error message? What do you expect to happen? What actually happens? You need to provide more information.

Comment: Need more information about your problem. However at first glance,Why not use a `DataTable` instead and then bind it to the `DataGridView`?

Comment: when I run the program it says "ColumnCount property cannot be set on a data-bound DataGridView control"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set ColumnCount,just use 
StudentInfoDataFridView.Columns.Add("whatever");

Comment: sir can you give me some example how to do that?

Comment: DataTable studentInfoDataGrid = new DataTable();
studentInfoDataGrid.Columns.Add("ID");
studentInfoDataGrid.Columns.Add("FirstName");
studentInfoDataGrid.Columns.Add("LastName");
studentInfoDataGrid.Columns.Add("Course");
studentInfoDataGrid.Columns.Add("StudentSection");
studentInfoDataGrid.Columns.Add("StudentNumber");

//now you have a datatable with those columns in it

DataRow row = studentInfoDataGridView.NewRow();
row[0] = //blablabla for the next cells
studentInfoDataGridView.Rows.Add(row);
studentInfoDataGridView.DataSource = studentInfoDataGrid;